# how to get all selected row key values using checkbox selection of devexpress gridview in mvc in javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am using devexpress gridview in mvc with checkboxes. I want all selected checkbox key values  of gridview to controller when i am selecting some checkboxes with paging in gridview

Comment: Why don't you contact DX support directly?

Answer (score 1):

Use recommendations from the [How to get all GridView selected keys and pass them to a Controller](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E20065) sample.

Answer (score 0):

Key values of all selected checkboxes in the gridview can be retrieved by iterating though all the rows of gridview one by one using a simple loop and checking if the checkbox is selected or not. If yes you can retrieve key value of that row using built in functions(sorry i don't remember the function name, that you need to look yourself) and save the retrieved values in an array. These values can then be passed on to controller. Remember, everytime you check/uncheck even one box you still need to iterate all rows again. Hope it would solve your problem.